# Multiple Match Condition in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames, and I wish to insert the values of one dataframe into another (let's call them data1 and data2).
data1 consists of col1 and col2, data2 consists of col1,col2 and col3. I want to be able to match data1$col1 with data2$col1 with the condition if data2$col2="Address" the the return value will be data2$col3.

What I have done so far is the following:

```
Result <- data2$col3[which(data1$col1 %in%  data1$col2)&
                                           data2$col2=="Address" ]
```

However, I am not getting any results and its all NA and it says

```
"replacement has 42 rows, data has 43" , ":
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

The other question that I have is if I want to change the condition to:

```
Result <- data2$col3[which(data1$col1 %in%  data1$col2)&
                                           data1$col2=="NA" ] 

ERORR:
"Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"
```

So let me provide more information on this:

```
data1=data.frame(col1=c("id1","id1","id2","id2","id3","id3","id3","id4", "id5"),
                 col2=c("A", "A","B","B", "C", "C", "C", "D"))                                                                                                                    
data2=dataframe(col1=c("id1","id1","id2","id2","id3","id3","id3","id4"),
                col2=c("Address", "Phone","Address","Phone", "Address", "Phone", "Contact", "Address") ,
                col3= c("102 J st", "91625631526", "105 N St", "50123659442", "58 M St", "58643183452", "Asghar", "Taylor St,")
```

I am trying to match the col1 of both datframes and if data2$col2=="Address" then return the value from data2$col3 . for example "id1" matches in both then it should look for col2 in data2 to see if its "Address" then the result should be. "102 J st"

Comment: Perhaps provide `data1` and `data2` using `dput()`

Comment: You need to demonstrate with a simple example what you mean by the request: "match data1$col1 with data2$col1 with the condition if data2$col2="Address" the the return value will be data2$col3."

Comment: Welcome to SO! I really like the `SQL`-like syntax in `tidyverse` for merging and matching, perhaps something like `dplyr::left_join()` would help here? Might make writing the logic easier.

Answer (score 0):

You want the col3 of data2 only for the rows of data2 for which:

- value col1 of data2 is also in col1 of data1
- value of col2 of data2 is "Address".

With the data you provided, we should have "102 J st","105 N St",   "58 M St"  and  "Taylor St".

So it is like below:

```
# Data
data1 = data.frame(col1 = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id3", "id3", "id3", "id4", "id5"),
                   col2 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D","E")) 
data2 = data.frame( col1 = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id3", "id3", "id3", "id4"),
 col2 = c("Address", "Phone", "Address", "Phone", "Address", "Phone","Contact", "Address") ,
 col3 = c("102 J st","91625631526", "105 N St","50123659442", "58 M St", "58643183452","Asghar", "Taylor St"))
# Result: all the addresses of interest
data2$col3[(data2$col1 %in% data1$col1) & data2$col2=="Address"]
#In case it is needed: all the addresses of interest with id 
data2[(data2$col1 %in% data1$col1) & data2$col2=="Address",c("col1","col3")]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The data frame is as follows: data1=data.frame(col1=c("id1","id2","id3","id5"),col2=c("102 Apt D","52 Meadows Ave","2516 John St","18 J st")) 
 data2=data.frame(col1=c("id1","id1","id1","id2","id2","id3","id4","id5"),col2=c("Address","contact","Phone","Address","contact","Address","Address","Address",), col3=c("A","B","C","D")) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you also provide what you expect to get as a result ? I'm confused because in your example, col2 are different in data1 and data2, so it's a bit strange. And also it would seem more interesting to get the column 2 from data1 (which contains a real address) instead of column 3 from data2

Comment: Hello, thanks for the update. The previous answer I gave was still correct, so I just updated the code to use your data and added one result with the id in col1, in case you needed it. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What if it didnt find any math? is it possible to add something in the code that it reflects the fact that if it didnt match, put "NA" in that row.

Comment: To get the id from data1 that did not have a match in data2, you can do this (assuming all people in data2 have an address):
`library(dplyr);
full_join(data2 %>% filter(col2 == "Address") %>% select("col1", "col3"), data1 %>% select("col1"),   by = "col1")%>%  unique()`
If it is possible that people in data2 don't have an address, try this instead:
`full_join(data2 %>% filter(col2 == "Address") %>% select("col1", "col3"), full_join(data1,data2,by="col1") %>% select("col1"), by = "col1")%>%  unique()`